# How to connect bezier curve endpoints with straight line

Tags: bezier-curves

I create beziel curve like this:

[image]

Then I press alt+c to connect endpoints and I get this:
[image]

But I want this:
[image]

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to do it:

- Select your vertices and press <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to *Free Handles* mode.
- Select your vertices and the bottom handles and press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to flatten on the Y axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Box the handles.**

The directions of the handles of a bezier curve are the gradient the curve takes at that point.  For the flat bottom you want a flat gradient.  The gradient at the hemisphere point of the circle has a gradient directly up.

Add a bezier circle. Remove the lowest point.  Select and set the handle types of the "corner" points to 'FREE'. <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> Adjust the handles as shown below.  The curve of the bezier will depend on the opposite handle of next point

As long as the 4 points are on the line, thats the two corner points and the handles inbetween, are on one line there will be a straight line between them.  Adust the other corner points to change curve to suit.

[image]